# Money owed to credit cards called "positive balances" or "negative balances"?

Tags: credit-card, accounts, terminology, balance

Q1)  If my Visa credit card has a zero balance and then I charge something on the Visa, do I now have a "positive balance" or a "negative balance"?

Q2)  Same question for a utility account like a power bill.  What is my balance called when I owe money?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term for money owed to you by a company would be a **credit balance**.  Consider, when an item is *credited* to your account, it's in your favor.

Whereas, money you owe to a company may be referred to simply as a **balance**, or **balance owing**, or less frequently a **debit balance**.  A related term **balance due** would be the payment you owe in the current period, i.e. not representative of the entire amount owed.

I don't think the terms "positive balance" or "negative balance" are considered *idiomatic* in business.  Rather, accounting terms like [**debit** and **credit**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debits_and_credits) have taken hold instead – and are often a source of confusion.

But I suggest that if you have a *negative balance* on a credit card, it's a credit balance in your favor.  Unless they mix it up.

Comment: But it's the opposite if you have a *negative balance* in your checking account :)

Comment: @bstpierre Yes indeedy, that's a good example to highlight that context matters.